# Is it possible to import an entire namespace in PHP?

Tags: php, namespaces

If I have a project with a set of core functions that are in a namespace `CORE` and a set of project files that are in a namespace `PROJECT`, is there anyway I can give the files in `PROJECT` access to all of the functions in `CORE` without having to prefix `CORE\`?

I know I can `use function CORE\func1` for each function, but I am wondering if there is anyway to blanket `use CORE`

EDIT:

Here are my test files:

**index.php**:

```
<?php
namespace PROJECT;
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include_once 'core.php';
include_once 'project.php';

// both work
print \CORE\corefunc();
print projfunc();

// Works
// use function CORE\corefunc;
// print corefunc();

// Does not work
use CORE;
print corefunc();
```

**core.php**:

```
<?php
namespace CORE;
function corefunc()
{
    return "I'm CORE<br>";
};
```

**project.php**:

```
<?php
namespace PROJECT;
function projfunc()
{
    return "I'm PROJECT<br>";
}
```

**Output in browser**:

```
I'm CORE
I'm PROJECT

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function corefunc() in /development/FWTest/index.php:18 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /development/FWTest/index.php on line 18
```

Comment: Don't mean to sound rude or something, but couldn't you just try it out on your code?

Comment: I did and it doesn't work, hence my question

Comment: I don't understand what I am missing. The downvotes and your comment suggest that I am being stupid and this should work. What am I missing?

Comment: `use` does **not** `include()` or `require()` any files, it "just tells PHP where to look". The downvotes are probably because you had no code in the first place

Comment: Sure, and I am including the actual files manually (in this example, for the purposes of understanding this part of PHP namespaces)

Comment: I have now added code.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have `functions-core.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Core;
function test() {
    return "Core-Test";
}
```

and `functions-project.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Project;
function test() {
    return "Project-Test";
}
```

and in your `main.php` you do:

```
<?php

include ('functions-core.php');
include ('functions-project.php');
```

If you would remove the namespaces from the files, you'd get an error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare test() (previously declared in ...

Using namespaces PHP knows that those are "different" functions and can load them without error. You could then access like you did using

```
echo Core\test();
echo Project\test();
```

in your `main.php`. Hth

Comment: I understand this. I want to know if I can do anything with PHP namespaces that allows me to use classes and functions in another known namespace that has no function clashes, as if it were my native namespace. Imagine the core namespace has 50 classes/functions, I could put 50 `use CORE\class1;` or `use function CORE\func1` entries in to get that effect, but I am wondering if there is a way to get all classes/functions in one go. I would have guessed `use CORE` might work, but it doesn't.